# chunking an array in jade template

Tags: templates, pug

I have an array, and a mixin that takes an array as a param.
How would I chunk the array into sections of four and pass to the mixin?

So something sort of like this but better and working:

```
 each index, i in myArray
     if i%4 == 0
         +carouselItem([myArray[i], myArray[i+1], myArray[i+2], myArray[i+3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a bit different approach: convert your array into two-dimensional array in your request handler function and then perform iteration over two-dimensional array (array of arrays) in your Jade template.

With that approach the template will be much simpler and all conversion will happen inside the handler method (controller) where you can have access to different libraries etc.

Example:
In order to convert an array into two-dimensional array you could use following method:

```
function arrayTo2DArray (list, howMany) {
    var result = []; input = list.slice(0); 
    while(a[0]) { 
        result.push(a.splice(0, howMany)); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

And your request handler could look as follows:

```
exports.handler = function(req, res) {

    // myArray with some values

    res.render('template' { 
        myArray: arrayTo2DArray(myArray, 4) 
    }
}
```

If your `myArray` was, say, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`, `arrayTo2DArray(myArray, 4)` would return

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
]
```

Your Jade template could look like this (much simpler)

```
each values in myArray
    +carouselItem(values)
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: cheers tom, I had considered pre-processing the data but it would mean another layer - retrieving data, checking template, then chunking depending on browser size. I was hoping that i could push this complexity into the template as its the only one that needs preprocessing. Is a compromise possible? ie to write the js for chunking inside the template. I know you can write simple js using - but can you write more complex multi-line code? or can you execute an external piece of code?

Comment: ok, just reading this: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/796 (Allow multiline JS var definition) which has a big no form the maintainer (TJ) so I'm guessing that what I want to do would be considered bad practice, so pre-processing it is then.

Comment: @neilmanuell, all depends on your preferences and approach. I am using this pattern as it works for me and in many, many cases it saved me enormous amount of time during maintenance and changes. As you can probably read in the mention (and other comments) - TJ Holowaychuk wants to split responsibilities i.e. template for rendering and controller (aka request handler) for fetching and preparing data. I am sure you may find different approaches - but the final goal is to deliver software ASAP to a specific quality - and in my opinion pre-processing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar.

**SOLUTION:**

**Step # 1:** Add the necessary instance method to the Array class prototype:

Place this in the controller that calls/renders the view where you will be calling that mixin.

```
Array.prototype.each_slice = function (size, callback) {
    for (let i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i += size) {
        callback.call(this, this.slice(i, i + size));
    }
};
```

**Step # 2:** Render properly the array slices in your pug file.

```
if myArray && myArray.length > 0
    - myArray.each_slice(2, (slice) => {
    +carouselItem(...slice)
    - })
```

For example, I just did this using Node.js + Express + Pug(ex Jade)

This is the home controller:
***controllers/home.controller.js***

```
const {CodingSkill} = require('../models');
const {errorsHelper} = require('./../utilities');

Array.prototype.each_slice = function (size, callback) {
    for (let i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i += size) {
        callback.call(this, this.slice(i, i + size));
    }
};

exports.index = async (request, response, next) => {

    try {
        const codingSkills = await CodingSkill.find({}).sort({percentage: -1});
        response.render('home/index', {pageTitle: 'Any title', codingSkills})
    } catch (error) {
        request.toastr.error(error, 'Server Error!');
        errorsHelper.status500(error, next);
    }

}
```

This is the home index view that includes the partial:
*views/home/index.pug*

[image]

And finally this is the partial:
*views/home/includes/skills_dynamic.pug*

```
section#skills.skills.section-bg
    .container
        .section-title
            h2 Skills
            p
                | Magnam dolores commodi suscipi. Necessitatibus eius consequatur ex aliquid fuga eum quidem. Sit sint consectetur velit. Quisquam quos quisquam cupiditate. Et nemo qui impedit suscipit alias ea. Quia fugiat sit in iste officiis commodi quidem hic quas.
        if codingSkills && codingSkills.length > 0
            - codingSkills.each_slice(2, (slice) => {
            .row.skills-content
                .col-lg-6(data-aos='fade-up')
                    .progress
                        span.skill
                            | #{slice[0].name}
                            i.val #{slice[0].percentage}%
                        .progress-bar-wrap
                            .progress-bar(role='progressbar', aria-valuenow=slice[0].percentage, aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
                if (slice[1])
                    .col-lg-6(data-aos='fade-up', data-aos-delay='100')
                        .progress
                            span.skill
                                | #{slice[1].name}
                                i.val #{slice[1].percentage}%
                            .progress-bar-wrap
                                .progress-bar(role='progressbar', aria-valuenow=slice[1].percentage, aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')


            - })
```

**Visual Result:**

[image]